# error loading text as variable from file and check it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

this is some code it suppose to check for adb.exe in a location then if it exist will proceed to code if not will ask user to input location manually and check again if location is right will save the input in file "dontremoveoredit" to use it next time user open the bat file

---

the problem is if the file is empty or contain path it will crash the bat and close

```
:: @echo off
If exist "C:\Program Files\ui\adb.exe" (
    goto yes
) else (
    goto adbexist
    ) 

:yes
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\ui"
:: @cd/d "%~dp0"
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe devices
adb connect localhost:5037
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
echo Yes Was Executed
Pause>nul
Exit 

:no    
msg * "Couldn't find The adb.exe in Default Bath"
ping localhost -n 3 >Nul 
goto noadbtext


:adbexist
If exist dontremoveoredit (
    goto adbexist1
) else (
    goto no
    ) 

:adbexist1
set /p var=<dontremoveoredit
if [%var%] == [] (
    goto noadbtext
) else (
    goto lala
    )
:lala
If exist %var%\adb.exe (
    set PATH=%PATH%;%var%"
    adb.exe kill-server
    adb.exe devices
    adb connect localhost:5037
    goto dns
) else (
    msg * "Make Sure You Entered The Right Path To UI"
    goto noadbtext
    ) 

:noadbtext
break>"dontremoveoredit"
set /p EmulatorUIBath=Enter Your Emulator's UI folder Path : 
If exist "%EmulatorUIBath%\adb.exe" (
    @echo %EmulatorUIBath%>> "dontremoveoredit"
    goto adbexist2
) else (
    msg * "Make Sure You Entered The Right Path To UI"
    goto noadbtext
    ) 


:adbexist2
set PATH=%PATH%;%EmulatorUIBath%"
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe devices
adb connect localhost:5037
echo adb Exist2 
Pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: oo, I like re-editing ADB scripts to be to best practices etc each time I root my phone, I'll take a crack just because this is fun so long as you don;t mind if I completely over-hall the logic to make it tight

Comment: recommended `if` syntax: `if "%var%" == ""`. See[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282362/batch-cmd-exits-as-i-enter-the-input-with-space) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are my laptop is about to die but this should do the needful nicely. :)

**Slightly Updated Version I mentioned I woudl post.**

```
@(
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_ConfigFilePath=%~0dpn_DO_NOT_REMOVE.dat"
  SET "_ADBPath="
  SET "_eLvl=0"
  SET "ECHO_RW=Call :Echo_Color CF "
  SET "ECHO_GB=Call :Echo_Color 20 "
  SET "ECHO_AB=Call :Echo_Color B0 "
  SET "ECHO_LY=Call :Echo_Color 1E "
  SET "ECHO_YL=Call :Echo_Color E1 "
  SET "ECHO_YR=Call :Echo_Color EC "
  SET "ECHO_RY=Call :Echo_Color CE "
  SET "ECHO_BY=Call :Echo_Color 1E "
  )

CALL :Main

(
  ECHO. Script Completed With ErrorLevel of %_eLvl%
  ENDLOCAL
  Exit /B %_eLvl%
)

:Echo_Color
  ECHO.>"%~2"
  FINDStr /A:%~1 /I ".*" "%~2" NUL
  DEL /F /Q "%~2" >nul 2>nul
GOTO :EOF

:Main
  REM Checing for ADB
  CALL :CheckADB

  IF /I %_eLvl% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO. Error Encountered, Exiting!
  ) ELSE (
    CALL :RunADB
  )
  PAUSE

GOTO :EOF



:CheckADB
  REM Check For ADB Installed in Program Directories
  FOR /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A IN ('
    SET ProgramFiles
  ') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('
      WHERE /R "%%A" /F "adb.exe" 2^>nul
    ') DO (
      ECHO Found ADB here: "%%~a"
      SET "_ADBPath=%%~a"
    )
  )
  REM ECHO.Finished Where Loop
  IF NOT DEFINED _ADBPath (
    ECHO. ADB Install not Found, checking Config file.
    IF EXIST "!_ConfigFilePath!" (
      ECHO. Config File Exists checking contents..
      FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
        TYPE "!_ConfigFilePath!"
      ') DO (
        ECHO. Saved ADB Path Found: "%%~A" in Config file.
        IF EXIST "%%~A" (
          SET "_ADBPath=%%~A"
        ) ELSE (
          ECHO. Saved ADB Path "%%~A" Does Not Exist!  Deleteing Config File.
          CALL :Get_ADB_Path_From_User
        )
      )
    ) ELSE (
      CALL :Get_ADB_Path_From_User
    )
  )
GOTO :EOF


:Get_ADB_Path_From_User
  CLS
  REM COLOR CF
  ECHO.
  COLOR 1E
  FOR %%A IN (
    "==========================================================="
    "=           ADB was not detected on your system           ="
    "==========================================================="
  ) DO (
    REM ECHO.>"%%~A"
    REM FINDStr /A:CF /I ".*" "%%~A" NUL
    REM DEL /F /Q "%%~A" >nul 2>nul
    %ECHO_RY% "%%~A"
  )
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  %ECHO_AB% "Please enter a custom path to ADB below."
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  SET /P "_TmpADBPath=What Is the Path to your ADB Install? "
  CLS
  IF NOT EXIST "%_TmpADBPath%" (
    %ECHO_RW% "==========================================================="
    %ECHO_RW% "==                                                       =="
    %ECHO_RW% "==    Unable to Verify that The path Provided Exists     =="
    %ECHO_RW% "==                                                       =="
    %ECHO_RW% "==========================================================="
    SET "_eLvl=1"
    GOTO :EOF
  ) ELSE (
    COLOR 2F
    SET "_ADBPath=%_TmpADBPath%"
    ECHO.===========================================================
    ECHO. Path Exists:
    ECHO. 
    ECHO. "%_TmpADBPath%"
    ECHO. 
    ECHO. ===========================================================
    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    CHOICE /M "Save this Path for future Use?"
    IF /I "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" (
      ECHO.%_TmpADBPath%>"%_ConfigFilePath%"
      ECHO.
      ECHO. Saved to: "%_ConfigFilePath%"
    ) ELSE (
      ECHO.
      ECHO. Okay, Will only use it temporarily.
    )
      COLOR
  )
GOTO :EOF

:RunADB
    "%_ADBPath%" kill-server
    "%_ADBPath%" devices
    "%_ADBPath%" connect localhost:5037
    Echo.
    Echo.
    Echo.
    Echo.Yes Was Executed
    Pause>nul
Exit
```

Comment: @Mr.ZQS I amended slightly but mostly just fluff, will post amended version in 30+ minutes from train, but above should work fine just with extra unneeded echos and pauses

Comment: it's fine code just will do some edit to refine it as it won't check the path if it's predefined jst takes it and start prograssing the code which won'yt be excecuted duo to lake of adb.exe that's needed inside thr path

Comment: @Mr.ZQS  Sure, thats a simple change on ordering in that section.  I had thought that might be prefered, but used the logic you had where it only looked for the preference file if it did not find the ADB installed in case it was on purpose.  Glad to help!  :)

Comment: @Mr.ZQS actually I missunderstood.  I thought the user would enter the fullpath to adb including "ADB.exe" They might.  We cshould actually amend it to see if it ends with `\ADB.exe`, `\ADB`, `\`, or has no trailing slash and none of the other options) to see if we need to ammend anything.

Comment: the code really works fine and does what i would never could achieve xD
it's just few edits to prevent some crashes when i implant the code to the main code i work on xD

Comment: @Mr.ZQS Glad to help! :)