# How to automatically close cmd window after when i choose the option?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
cls
:start
echo.
echo 1. Multiplayer
echo 2. Singeplayer
echo.
echo.
set /p x=Pick:
IF '%x%' == '%x%' GOTO Item_%x%

:Item_1
start /MIN /D"D:\games\Battlefield 2142 - Deluxe Edition\mods\bf2142\Tools\BF2142Unlocker64" BF2142Unlocker.exe
GOTO Start

:Item_2
start /MIN /D"D:\games\Battlefield 2142 - Deluxe Edition" BF2142_offline_4gb.exe
GOTO Start
```

i'm trying to solve it but i am noob shortcuts take up a lot of space on the desktop so I'm trying to run it with bat file

Comment: `IF '%x%' == '%x%' GOTO Item_%x%` can just be `GOTO Item_%x%`. `IF '%x%' == '%x%'` will be true and only true and nothing but true (except the user provokes a syntax error by including spaces into the input that [break the `if` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282362/batch-cmd-exits-as-i-enter-the-input-with-space/48282847?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C39.3505#48282847)). Tip: take a look at `choice /?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
start /MIN /D"D:\games\Battlefield 2142 - Deluxe Edition" BF2142_offline_4gb.exe
exit
```

Comment: You should use `exit /B` rather than `exit`…

Answer (score 0):

The command `exit` might be what you want to use