# 'If' command does not appear to work with '%ver%' string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a problem trying to use the `if` command in my batch file.

```bash
if %ver%==Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861] echo true
```

There is no `echo` despite the output from `ver` being:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861]
```

Any tips?

Comment: We need to see the code which was used to define the environment variable named `ver`.

Comment: This is only one part of the problem. There is a second [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48282847/2152082)

Comment: A space is a command delimiter.  You need to enclose string comparisons in quoutes. How else would it know if the command you want to run is Windows or ECHO.

Answer (score 2):

`ver` is a [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ver), not an environment variable so you can run `ver`, but not `%ver%`.

```
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.2715]

C:\>%ver%
'%ver%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>echo %ver%
%ver%
```

I recommend to pipe the output of `ver` and search for the version you are looking for:

```
ver|find "10.0.22621.2861">NUL && (echo true) || (echo wrong version)
```

Explanation of `>NUL`:
The `find` command prints out every finding of the searched string. In this case, it is the Windows version string, which is shown in the 1st example using `ver`. This is neither wanted nor needed. It's only relevant to know if the Windows version matches a searched version. Hence the standard ouput of the `find` command is streamed to NUL, not to the console.